# HTML + Laravel + npm + package.json workflow

Tags: laravel, npm

I am wondering in how I should include my npm packages into my HTML. I have added *"slidebars": "2.0.2"* to my *package.json*. After that, I ran *npm install*. So far so good.

Now, I am new with both Laravel and npm. I am trying to use the "mix" feature provided in Laravel like this:

```
mix
  .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
  .version();
```

Does that automatically compile all the packages provided in the package.json into the single app.js + app.css? Or do I manually need to import the CSS + JS from the *slidebars*-plugin, like: `<link href="/node_modules/slidebars/dist/slidebars.css" rel="stylesheet">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the css, the easiest way would to copy your css files to `resources/assets/` and then link it to your `app.scss` like this:

```
@import "package.scss"
```

As for the `JS`, you can combine your vendor JS files into one and copy them to the public directory like this

```
mix.js([
    'node_modules/package/dist/package.min.js',
    'node_modules/package2/dist/package2.min.js',
    'node_modules/package3/dist/package3.min.js',
], 'public/js/vendors.js');
```

Then in your view, you just include `/js/vendors.js`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried adding @import "node_modules/slidebars/dist/slidebars.css"; but the "npm run dev" throws me this error: http://pastebin.com/HeFwUdtk

Comment: You did not copy as I said. the `app.scss` file seats in `resources/assets/sass/`, please move your files there or manually reference node_modules `../../../node_modules...`

Comment: I think its cleaner to not copy the asset. But adding the "../../../" fixed it. Thanks. Although, how come that importing bootstrap without finding the root path works? This seems to be successful: @import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

Comment: Good if it helped, you can mark my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: After some further testing, the JS section of this answer does not seem to work. Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428025/javascript-load-order-laravel

Comment: Try to replace `mix.js()` with `mix.scripts()`. See docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#working-with-scripts